# How to test typescript function locally manually in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

sorry a rookie question, I am using react and typescript (via create-react-app) and if I have some totally non-UI javascript code (a module I am working on to work with some REST api), something along the lines like this:

src/lib/rest.tsx

```
export const getUser = async function (
    username: string,
) {
    let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/auth/`, {
        username
    });
    return response;
};
```

I am wondering how can I test this function locally in a REPL or browsers's dev tools, before putting it into real use. I think I have two difficulties right now:

1. webpack seems not even packaing this module into the code now, if I open Chrom's dev tools I can see other tsx files but not this one, simply becasue I am not importing this module anywhere I think.
2. even if it is packaged I dont know how to `import` this module in a REPL or the dev tool console because first I dont know what is the correct syntax here, Would it be `import src/lib/rest.tsx`? Also seems I cannot import any module in a REPL because import can only happen inside a module.

The workflow here is just I have written some simple typescript function and I want to run them in a REPL like enviorment so I can make sure they are working before using it anywhere or starting to write unit/integration tests against them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1 is correct, your new module is not imported and thus not bundled by webpack.

I don't think you could use `import` syntax in console atm. But there are 2 ways you could try.

Just import your code in one of the bundled file, if you are using dev server, change will be reflected to browser automatically:

```
import { getUser } from '../../lib/rest';

getUser().then(console.log);
```

Or attach it to window so you could play with it in console:

```
import { getUser } from '../../lib/rest';

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.getUser = getUser;
}
```